# Passing params to a partial in slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
Rails 3.2
Ruby 2.15
```

I have a somewhat complex view app/views/tickets/show.html.slim. Inside this view, I render various sections of the the ticket

One section is called customer_info. Here's what I have:

```
render 'tickets/sections/customer_info', locals: { customer_info: CustomerInfo.new, ticket: @ticket }
```

In my app/views/tickets/sections/_customer_info.html.slim, I have:

```
= form_for(customer_info) do |f|
  - :ticket_id = ticket.id
  = f.hidden_field :ticket_id
  .form-horizontal-column.customer-info
    .form-group
      = f.label :first_name
      = f.text_field :first_name
    .form-group
      = f.label :last_name
      = f.text_field :last_name
    .actions = f.submit 'Save'
  .clear
```

I am however getting the following error message:

```
_customer_info.html.slim:2: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
; :ticket_id = ticket.id; 
          ^
```

I am starting to learn .slim. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish on the 2nd line.  You can't set a symbol to an object.

Comment: I am trying to set s hidden field with the value ticket.id

Comment: remove that line.  Do something like `= f.hidden_field :ticket_id, value: ticket.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a symbol to something - they are immutable.  You can remove the 2nd line do do something like:

```
= form_for(customer_info) do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :ticket_id, :value => ticket.id
  ...
```

Comment: Now I am getting the following error message: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: Is it because I am passing CustomerInfo.new, which is null at this point?